# Margin issue only in a certain media query

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, margin

I am running into a strange issue that is throwing off my whole page in the media query range of `@media screen and (min-width: 640px) and (max-width:840px)`. For some reason it looks like I am getting a `margin-left` applied to the first box-container that I have, but in my code there isn't `margin-left` set. I tried to apply the start of the div `blue-box-container` right after the sibling above it to eliminate the white-space, but that did not help.

Does anyone have any idea why I would be getting the white-space to the left of my first blue box?

If someone needs to see this live, I can add the website inside of my comments. Please comment if wanting it.

[image: margin can be seen here]

```
.blue-box-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.dark-blue-box, .light-blue-box {
    height: 33%;
    width: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
}
.dark-blue-box:hover .box-description-hover, .light-blue-box:hover .box-description-hover {
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
.dark-blue-box:hover .box-description-hover, .light-blue-box:hover .box-description-hover {
    display: block;
    font-size: .9em;
    padding-top: 5px;
    clear: both;
}
.dark-blue-box:hover .insideBoxWrap, .light-blue-box:hover .insideBoxWrap {
    padding: 3% 6%;
}
.dark-blue-box:hover .box-title, .light-blue-box:hover .box-title {
    padding-top: 7%;
}
.dark-blue-box:nth-child(3){
    background-color: #8fc9d6;
 }
.light-blue-box:nth-child(4){
    background-color: #45a5ba;
}
.dark-blue-box:nth-child(3):hover, .light-blue-box:nth-child(4):hover{
    background-color: purple;
}
.dark-blue-box:nth-child(5){
    background-color: #45a5ba;
 }
.light-blue-box:nth-child(6){
    background-color: #8fc9d6;
}
.insideBoxWrap {
    padding: 10% 30px;
}
.box-title {
    font-size: 2em;
}
.box-description {
    padding-top: 5px;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}
/*------Home Icons ------*/
.home-icon img {
    height: 52px;
    width: 52px;
    padding-right: 6%;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    float: left;
}
.dark-blue-box:hover .home-icon img, .light-blue-box:hover .home-icon img {
    height: 76px;
    width: 76px;
}
```

HTML - rather than attaching all of it for all the blocks, I have only applied two blocks to demonstrate the general sequence.

```
<div class="blue-box-container">
  <div class="dark-blue-box">
    <div class="insideBoxWrap">
        <div class="home-icon"><img src="/icons/screen6.png" alt=""></div>
        <div class="box-title">Brand Strategy</div>
        <div class="box-description">Digital Roadmap</div>
        <div class="box-description-hover">Hover View fdsf fdfsd fdsfds fdfsdf fdsfdsf fdsfdsf fdsfs
        fdsf fdfsd fdsfds fdfsdf fdsfdsf fdsfdsf fdsfsfdsf fdfsd fdsfds fdfsdf fdsfdsf fdsfdsf fdsfs</div>
    </div>
  </div><div class="light-blue-box">
    <div class="insideBoxWrap">
        <div class="home-icon"><img src="/icons/web2.png" alt=""></div>
        <div class="box-title">Development</div>
        <div class="box-description">That Outperforms</div>
        <div class="box-description-hover">Hover View fdsf fdfsd fdsfds fdfsdf fdsfdsf fdsfdsf fdsfs
        fdsf fdfsd fdsfds fdfsdf fdsfdsf fdsfdsf fdsfsfdsf fdfsd fdsfds fdfsdf fdsfdsf fdsfdsf fdsfs</div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: I would like to see the website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple solutions possible, I would suggest adding `float` to the boxes:

```
.dark-blue-box, .light-blue-box {
    height: 33%;
    width: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
```

It fixes your issue.

Comment: This did it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can add a negative value on that box to eliminate the white space.

```
.insideBoxWrap {
    position: relative;
    left: -10px;
}
```

Comment: That would make all of my `blue-box-container`'s to shift left then.

Answer (score 1):

I think

```
.insideBoxWrap {
    padding: 10% 30px;
}
```

is causing the white space issue. You are giving 30px padding on left and right so all your elements inside `.insideBoxWrap` are moving to the right by 30px. And since there is no background color on insideBoxWrap, white space is appearing.